# Adding 1 to each entry of continued fractions

Tags: continued-fractions

Here we denote $[a_0,...,a_n]$ as the continued fraction of some rational number. If I take $p/q=[a_0,a_1,...,a_n]$ to $p'/q'=[a_0+1,a_1+1,...,a_n+1]$, are there any nice properties I can say about $p'/q'$?

Comment: Personally, *unknown*, but fascinating question.  If I was attacking this question, my *first stop* would be Chapter 1 (only) of [this book](https://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-497500429547.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/a06_cont_frac_Khinchin.pdf).  Then, my *second stop* would be [this book](http://www.ms.uky.edu/~sohum/ma330/files/Continued%20Fractions.pdf).

Comment: I find the question interesting as well. What kind of properties are you interested in: Bounds with respect to $p/q$, size of $q'$ relative to $q$, factorization properties of $p$ and $q$? With regards to the latter, I find it hard to expect there to be any nice results on the prime factorization of $p'$ and $q'$ - the examples I have computed seem to behave wildly in that regard.
I have written a short Python script for generating examples, I can share if you're interested.

Comment: When all $a_i$ are identical, you can compare them using this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4453134/expressing-the-continued-fraction-k-dots-k-as-a-closed-form (Note: since you are dealing with plus signs, use polynomials of the first kind instead, with a plus sign inside the square root)

Answer (score -1):

We have $p' = p + q$ and $q' = q$. This is because, in a continued fraction, the $n$-th term is $a_n = \lfloor \frac{p}{q} \rfloor$, the greatest integer less than or equal to $\frac{p}{q}$. But we have
$$
\frac{p}{q} = a_0 \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{a_1 \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{\ddots + \frac{1}{a_n}}}
$$
so
$$
\frac{p + 1}{q + 1} = a_0 \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{a_1 \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{\ddots + \frac{1}{a_n + \frac{1}{1}}}} = \frac{p'}{q'}
$$
where $p' = p + q$ and $q' = q$.

Comment: This is not correct. This is true if you add 1 to the first entry, but not each entry. For instance, if you take [7,4]=29/4 and [8,5]=41/5.